# Java 2D, Translation with the same amount on X and Y axis leads to different results

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d, java-2d

I'm just playing around with Java 2D for a weekend-project. What I try to accomplish is simply to load and draw an image at position 50,50 away from the origin. Now when I try to do exactly that, with

```
g2d.drawImage(imageLeft, 50, 50, 200, 200, null);
```

then I get the following:

[image]

Frankly, this confuses me a little bit. Why does the x-part of the translation get scaled differently than the y-part? What is going on here? Must be an obvious beginner's mistake, but I cannot figure it out the reason for this behavior for the life of me ;-)

The complete code I use to draw the image is:

```
final IsogenWindow window = new IsogenWindow();
final BufferedImage imageLeft = loadImage(new File(getClass().getResource("/texture/tile1.png").toURI()));
final Graphics2D g2d = Graphics2D)window.getGraphics();

window.setSize(1000, 1000);
window.setVisible(true);

g2d.drawImage(imageLeft, 50, 50, 200, 200, null);
```

EDIT 1:
To try out DontRelaX' suggestion, I changed my code so a panel is added to the JFrame and its Graphic2D object is used for drawing:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(null);
this.renderPanel = new JPanel();
getContentPane().add(renderPanel);
final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)renderPanel.getGraphics();
...
g2d.drawImage(imageLeft, 50, 50, 200, 200, null);
```

Unfortunately, the result is still the same. But I think DontRelaX is on the right track. Any further suggestions?

EDIT 2: Basically DontRelaX' answer was correct. I indeed used not the renderPanel's Graphics2D but instead still the JFrame's Graphics2D object.

Cheers,
nanoquack

Comment: An alternative based on @DontRelaX' answer would be to measure the offset.

Comment: 1) `final Graphics2D g2d = Graphics2D)window.getGraphics();`  Bug in the making.  Graphics objects are transient and should not be cached. 2) `g2d.drawImage(imageLeft, 50, 50, 200, 200, null);` should be `g2d.drawImage(imageLeft, 50, 50, 200, 200, this);` 3) `getContentPane().setLayout(null);` unnecessary at best, a cause of bugs at worst. ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pixels count from left top corner of window, not gray place. Add panel to your window and draw on it.